# What does Shaka player do that the <video> tag alone doesn't do?

Tags: html5-video, webm, mpeg-dash, shaka

As I understand it, modern browsers have progressed to the point where a `<video>` tag can play an HLS or MPEG-DASH stream with no JavaScript.

Shaka Player (https://github.com/google/shaka-player) seems to be a JS library for... doing what the `<video>` tag already does.  And yet it's actively maintained.

What does Shaka provide that `<video>` doesn't?  When/why would I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand it, modern browsers have progressed to the point where a  tag can play an HLS or MPEG-DASH stream with no JavaScript.

Nope, that's not really the case.  Safari supports HLS natively, but that's about it.

JavaScript libraries for DASH and HLS use MediaSource Extensions (MSE) to push data to the browser's codec handling, meaning the manifests/playlists and segments can be fetched in whatever way the script wants.  While more complex, this is better for everyone as we can now use whatever distribution protocol/method we want without a years-long process of browser standardization.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning also that, while the Encrypted Media Extension spec does not mandate that MSE is required for encrypted/DRM protected video, it does note that people 'should be aware that many implementations only support decrypting media data provided via Media Source Extensions'.